# In Linux shell scripting if we want remove dupicate line, how can i do that except sort -u command

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, command

write a script name to read file name from the end user and remove duplicate line from in that file.

#! /bin/bash
read -p "Enter any file name to remove duplicate line:" $fname
sort -u $fname > tmp.txt
mv tmp.txt > $fname

## here duplicate line will  be remove but my content will be sorted but i don't that what should i do.

i want another method to remove duplicate line in shell scripting.

Comment: Given lines `a b a d`, should ouput be `a b d` or `b a d` ?

Comment: `cat -n file.in | sort -k2 -u -s | sort -n | cut -f 2- > file.out`

Answer (score -2):

You can remove duplicate lines by the 'uniq' command.

Comment: `uniq` only works on **sorted** data, which they explicitly **didn't** want.